# Default function has some invalid arguments in Powerapps canvas app

Tags: powerapps

I would like to create a global variable with a default value in the OnStart function of Powerapps. I used the below statement:

```
Set(gblRecordWorkOrderCurrent, Defaults('Work Orders'))
```

But I am getting the below errors:

> The function 'Default' has some invalid arguments. Name isn't valid
> 'Work Orders' isn't recognized.

Comment: Did you add the `Work Order` data source to your app (`View/Data source/Add`)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure you add the data source.
2. If you are using the variable as the Default for a PowerApps Form control, you'll have to make sure the data source supports [default values for each column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-defaults)

If you are trying to set a variable to a *record*, you can [`LookUp()` or `Filter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) the data source.

**Some ideas:**

```
Set(gblRecordWorkOrderCurrent,
    LookUp(DATASOURCE,
        Column = Whatever
    )
)
```

**OR**

```
Set(gblRecordWorkOrderCurrent,
    First(
        Filter(DATASOURCE,
            Column = Whatever
        )
    )
)
```